# QuickBlox update custom object without using ID

Tags: ios, chat, quickblox

I use QuickBlox for my chat app.

When updating/deleting a custom object, is it possible not to use object.ID? 
For example, I use a custom field "requestor_id" and "responder_id" to identify FriendRequest Custom Object. I need to update the status of a friend request to from "pending" to "approved".

I don't want to fetch the ID first in order to update it.

Is it possible to send along a dictionary like @{"responder_id": 123, @"requestor_id":234}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible. Deleting or updating take place only with object's ID.. so you need perform at last 2 actions:

- fetch items
- updating/deleting